# Two labels inside a grid in a button, how can I access them programatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, label

So I have a grid with many buttons, I need the buttons to have 2 distinct labels so I added them inside of a grid.

```
 <Button x:Name="Bid_0" Background="Blue" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  Opacity=".7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="0">
  <Grid  x:Name="Bid_0_Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="Bid_Price_0" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  UseLayoutRounding="True" Padding="0"/>
    <Label x:Name="Bid_Vol_0" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  UseLayoutRounding="True" Padding="0"/>
  </Grid>
</Button>
```

I have many of these buttons and I iterate them as follows:

```
        foreach (UIElement element in L2TraderGrid.Children)
        {
            var button = element as Button;                               

            if (button != null)
            {

                var name = button.Name.Split('_');

                if(name[0] == "Bid")
                {
                    BidButtons[int.Parse(name[1])] = button;
                }
                else if (name[0] == "Ask")
                {
                    AskButtons[int.Parse(name[1])] = button;
                }
            }
```

So when I have the individual buttons I need a way to access the labels from my code.

alternatively, can I iterate through my main grid to get all the grids inside of the buttons?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Bid_Price_0.Content = "text"; Or are you asking about how to access them based on the current button you are on while enumerating - based on the code above.. i'm guessing it is that. just want to confirm.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I have 40 buttons and need to iterate through them and set both labels when I have the button

Comment: You manage 40 buttons with multiple labels without MVVM? Sounds like a lot of spaghetti code to me...

Answer (score 1):

No need to add them inside a GRID. You can access Content property of button from code-behind. In you case eg: Bid_0.Content="your label"
Or you can even Bind the Button Content if you follow MVVM design.

Comment: That doesnt work as I need to have 2 different dynamic content in each button. I was doing this perviously when I had only one thing to set

Answer (score 1):

Its probably not the best solution. However, if you follow a naming convention with the "_Grid" after the button name you can do this. Im sure you want something more elegant.

```
  Grid myGrid = (Grid)this.FindName(button.Name+"_Grid");
        foreach (Control c in myGrid.Children )
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
            {
                Label l = c;
                l.Content = "text";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a UserControl and place my buttons inside it. Then I would embed the UserControl in the main grid. This way I would not need the complicated naming conventions.